# synctoy won't install with intel pentium M 755.2 GHz

Tags: installation, synctoy

I cannot sync files with synctoy from my laptop because it will not install, presumably  because laptop is only 755.2 Mhz intel pentium m (synctoy says it needs 1000GH computer). Is there a solution  (I love my laptop too much to change).

Comment: what error message do you get when trying to install?

Comment: Can I have that 755.2 GHz Pentium M? I'll pay you... $1000. More than enough for technology from the year 2345, yeah?

Comment: I doubt the install problem is because you have a Pentium M because the minimum requirements for SyncToy 2.1 (the latest version) is a Pentium III. Exactly what error message to you get when you try to install it? SyncToy does require at least Windows XP. Here's its [System Requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155#system-requirements).